# How do you print a variable as a string for the length of an input?

Tags: python

my task is when I type 'z' i get the outcome of 'w'.

This works.

However, if I input 'zzzz' only a single 'w' is outputted.

My question is how can I print 'w' for the number of times I enter z.

I am relatively new to StackOverflow. I'm sorry if I have broken any rules or my question is not correctly phrased.

```
z='w'
while True:
    plaintext=input('enter a word to get its ciphertext')            
    i=list(plaintext)
    print (i)
    if 'z' in plaintext
        print("w")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looping through the text to get all of the letters

```
z='w'
while True:
    plaintext=input('enter a word to get its ciphertext')
    i=plaintext

    for letter in i :
        if(letter == 'z'):
            print ('w')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overcomplicating it. The variable you get from input() is a string. Simply use [str.replace()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace).

```
while True:
    plaintext = input('enter a word to get its ciphertext')
    plaintext_rep = plaintext.replace('z','w')
    print(plaintext_rep)
```

Comment: I sure was! This code is perfect, works like a charm, Thank you!

Comment: @mr.brocklehursty glad I could help. Happy programming!